# Responsive background quistion

Tags: javascript, css, background

I am trying to get the pattern in the top bar repeat, I would like to have it responsive, so the size stays the same across multiple window sizes.
I added all the code in the link. http://www.codecademy.com/harmjanfl/codebits/ny7bes 
I thought I might needed to add some javascript but I am quite new to that:D.
if there is anything you need to know me, please ask.
thanks a lot!

Comment: Your page has 2 css classes that use background images: menu and boven.   Which is the the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove "background-size: cover" from .boven element to make the the background keep it's size.

Change this:

```
.boven {
     background: #202024 url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/black-thread.png');
     background-repeat: repeat;
    width: 
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
         -o-background-size: cover;
             background-size: cover;
}
```

to:

```
.boven {
     background: #202024 url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-  content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/black-thread.png');
     background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reaction, i want to have that the top bar has the same look as the menu bar. now it is just a solid color.